Event listener not working on <select> element
The "change" event listener is not responding in the browser


// mobile options
const selectElement = document.querySelector(select)

let spices = document.querySelector(".spices")
let milletAndPorridges = document.querySelectorAll(".millet")
let healthSupplements = document.querySelectorAll(".health")

let spicesProducts = document.querySelectorAll("")
let milletProducts = document.querySelectorAll("")
let healthSupplementProducts = document.querySelectorAll("")

selectElement.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    const selectedValue = event.target.value

    if (selectedValue === spices) {
        // this is just for testing purposes
        alert('SPice')
    }
})
<div class="sorting">
    <select name="" class="">
        <option value="default" class="default">Sort by Category</option>
        <option value="default" class="spices">Spices</option>
        <option value="sort-by-price" class="millets">Porridges & Millets</option>
        <option value="sort-by-popularity" class="health">Health Supplements</option>
    </select>
</div>



I tried the above javascript which didn't work, I also tried using a forEach loop on every option and adding a click listener to each option which didn't work also.

what is the value of your select variable here? The one you use for your querySelector
const selectElement = document.querySelector(select)

The browser console is reporting a specific error.  Your very first line of JavaScript attempts to use a variable which was never defined.

Aside from the seemingly-undefined select identifier: The value of an element is always a string. No string is going to match the element returned by querySelector, so selectedValue === spices will always be false.

select does not exist in this context const selectElement = document.querySelector(select)

as already stated above you are trying to compare the value of the selected option with an element returned by a querySelector  will always return false becuz for example you are basically comparing the string "Spices" with <option value="default" class="spices">Spices</option>

Clean up the event listener then decide how to use the value.
Here I added a class just to be clear.


const myselect = document.querySelector('select.my-select');
myselect.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  const selectedValue = event.target.value;
  console.log('Value:', this.value, ' Other way:', selectedValue);

  //decide what to do with the value here....
});
<div class="sorting">
  <select name="" class="my-select">
    <option value="default" class="default">Sort by Category</option>
    <option value="spicy" class="spices">Spices</option>
    <option value="sort-by-price" class="millets">Porridges & Millets</option>
    <option value="sort-by-popularity" class="health">Health Supplements</option>
  </select>
</div>






// mobile options
const selectElement = document.getElementsByName('drop_select')[0];
//changed .querySelector(select) to .getElementsByName('drop_select')[0]

let spices = document.querySelector(".spices")
let milletAndPorridges = document.querySelectorAll(".millet")
let healthSupplements = document.querySelectorAll(".health")

// let spicesProducts = document.querySelectorAll("")
// let milletProducts = document.querySelectorAll("")
// let healthSupplementProducts = document.querySelectorAll("")
//commented the above as it was giving warnings...
selectElement.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    const selectedValue = event.target.value;

    if (selectedValue === 'spices') {
        // this is just for testing purposes
        alert('SPice')
    }
})
<div class="sorting">
        <select name="drop_select" class="">
            <option value="default" class="default">Sort by Category</option>
            <option value="spices" class="spices">Spices</option>
            <!-- changed the value for spices -->
            <option value="sort-by-price" class="millets">Porridges & Millets</option>
            <option value="sort-by-popularity" class="health">Health Supplements</option>
        </select>
    </div>



HTML changes
<div class="sorting">
        <select name="drop_select" class="">
            <option value="default" class="default">Sort by Category</option>
            <option value="spices" class="spices">Spices</option>
            <!-- changed the value for spices -->
            <option value="sort-by-price" class="millets">Porridges & Millets</option>
            <option value="sort-by-popularity" class="health">Health Supplements</option>
        </select>
    </div>

The changes in JS
// mobile options
const selectElement = document.getElementsByName('drop_select')[0];
//changed .querySelector(select) to .getElementsByName('drop_select')[0]

let spices = document.querySelector(".spices")
let milletAndPorridges = document.querySelectorAll(".millet")
let healthSupplements = document.querySelectorAll(".health")

// let spicesProducts = document.querySelectorAll("")
// let milletProducts = document.querySelectorAll("")
// let healthSupplementProducts = document.querySelectorAll("")
//commented the above as it was giving warnings...
selectElement.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    const selectedValue = event.target.value;

    if (selectedValue === 'spices') {
        // this is just for testing purposes
        alert('SPice')
    }
})

Here are the changes that you need to do.
Upvote the answer if you found it helpful.
